# jQuery AJAX back button after changing html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, back

I know there are many questions about jQuery + Back button issues, but it seems that they're trying to maintain history features when clicking the browser back/forward buttons.

My question is that when clicking the back/forward button, how can I load ajax-affected html page?

For example,

1. In index.html, dynamically remove all "div" elements from the list using AJAX (jQuery.post()).
2. Press the browser back(or forward) button to go to newpage.html.
3. Press the browser forward(or back) button to go to index.html again.
4. PROBLEM: the html page contains the deleted "div" elements.

How should I load index.html with no "div" elements after step (3)?

I'm currently using jQuery and Django as backend.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery [history plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) to encode the application state. See their Demos page for examples of how to do what you want.

Comment: I've used this before and it saved me a lot of trouble and hassle. Its a good little plugin.